# How can I can I add functionality to my module so that the templates can be overwritten?

Tags: theming

How can I can I add functionality to my module so that the templates can be overwrittable like in drupal core. I want to be able to use my module with various themes, but change the required templates.

The only way I have seen to add is via drupal_get_path and explicitly specifiying a theme/module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your templates by implementing [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8), and when needing them in your module uses a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/arrays) rendered with the [`RendererInterface::render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!RendererInterface.php/function/RendererInterface%3A%3Arender/8) method on the renderer service.

Theme, or other modules, will then be able to declare override for your templates like they do for any others.

The [theme system overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/group/themeable/8) in Drupal documentation gives more details on this process.